# $3-$norm on $L^4$ space

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, measure-theory, banach-spaces

Is the space $L^4([0,1])$ endowed with $3-$norm a Banach space?

I prepare for an exam in functional analysis (undergraduate) and I think that compactness of $[0,1]$ might allow this statement to be true.

Comment: With $3$-norm do you mean $L^3$ norm?

Comment: yes 3-Norm is L³ norm

Comment: @ Open Ball: I thought The theorem of Fisher-Riesz ( "Normkonvergenzsatz") states L^p is a Banachspace with respect to L^p-norm ??

Comment: Indeed it does. I had something else in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not true. Every $L^3$ function can be approximated in the $L^3$-norm by step-functions. Those step-functions are all in $L^4$. If $L^4$ was a Banach space with respect to the $L^3$-norm this would imply $L^3\subset L^4$, but this is not true, as you should know.